# How to create dynamic elements inside global tabs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working with react  hooks, And encounter a problem where I have been stuck now.

I have one json data which I am getting whenever user `logs in` so by that I am creating one top bar which shows `user names` and when user click on those names I am showing some data which they have created or present for them in db, That data I am already getting in data

**MY data I am getting from server**

```
 let data=   [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Maxi",
    "myData": [
      {
        "data_name": "div1",
        "data_title": "div1 tittle"
      },
      {
        "data_name": "div1",
        "data_title": "div tittle"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Phill",
    "myData": [
      {
        "data_name": "div21",
        "data_title": "div21 tittle"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have one button on side on which I want to create new div, inside the name I have selected from top.

SO suppose I have listed the `topbar` and there are total of 3 data i.e 3 names, so if data length is smaller than 4 what I am doing, showing a plus button to create one more tab, so user can create one more tab and then they can create one div inside there each tab,

**What I have done**

I am populating the top bar as well as when I click on side button I am creating one `div` inside that selected tab.

**Issues I am facing**

- if length of data is less then four I am providing a plus button to create on more tab (give it default name), but I am not getting any idea how can I create the new one.
- when I click on side button to create one dive inside tab, and I go to other tab and come back again I want that created `div` should not gets deleted.
- Suppose I have 3 tabs (data) so when page loads the first tab data I want to show, but it is not showing up I need to click there only it is showing up.
- if the data is null then I can create up to 4 tabs this also I a=want some Idea to do it.

**I am linking my code sand box here so it will be easy to understand what I have done and what I am trying to do**

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-flower-61lxt?file=/src/App.js)

Here in code sand box I have written all my code please check it out.

I have explained every thing what I a m trying to do, I know how to code but not getting any idea or approach.

if there is no data for user then I will start creating tabs and nested elements from 1 for that user.

in each there will be a save button for each new element created, so I will do that, my only consern is to not to loss data on ui when I go one tab to other once I created them

```
export default function App() {
  const [active_menu, setactive_menu] = useState(0);
  const [nestedData, setnestedData] = useState(null);

  let data1 = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Maxi",
      myData: [
        {
          data_name: "div1",
          data_title: "div1 tittle"
        },
        {
          data_name: "div1",
          data_title: "div tittle"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Phill",
      myData: [
        {
          data_name: "div21",
          data_title: "div21 tittle"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  const Tab_click = (index, li) => {
    setactive_menu(index);
    setnestedData(li);
  };

  const Create_element = () => {
    //here I don't know how to create new elements
  };
  const addnewTab=()=>{
    
  }
  return (
    <div className="App row">
      {data1.map((li, index) => (
        <div className="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" key={index}>
          <div
            className={
              index === active_menu
                ? "row dashboard_single_cont_active"
                : "row dashboard_single_cont"
            }
            onClick={() => Tab_click(index, li)}
          >
            <div className="dashboard_name col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
              {li.name}
            </div>
            <div
              className={
                active_menu === index
                  ? "dashboard_option_active col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"
                  : "dashboard_option col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"
              }
              align="center"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      {data1.length < 4 && (
       <span
       onClick={addnewTab}
       >ADD</span>
      )}
      <div className="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11">
        <div className="row">
          {nestedData !== null &&
            nestedData.myData.map((li, index) => (
              <div className="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <NEsted data={li} />
                <br></br>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <RightBar Create_element={Create_element} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues You are Facing

1. If length of data is less than four I am providing a plus button to create on more tab (give it default name), but I am not getting any idea how can I create the new one.

Here you want to get a new name, i.e. a form on the page with a text input, random generate name, use a prompt as I did below. Call `setData` and use a functional state update to spread existing data into a *new* array and append a new data object.

```
const addNewTab = () => {
  /**
   * window.prompt is just a quick way to request input from user. 
   */
  const name = window.prompt('Enter Name');

  /**
   * logic to generate next id, but could be anything really
   */
  const id = generateId();

  if (name) {
    setData((data) => [...data, new Data(id, name)]);
  }
};
```

2. When I click on side button to create one dive inside tab, and I go to other tab and come back again I want that created `div` should not gets deleted.

A couple things going on here. First, you defined `data1` in the function body so it is reset *every* render cycle. Keep the data in state, `data` can be provided as initial state. Second, you need to add the created elements. Do this by updating state.

Move `data1` out of the component and define local component state initialized with `data` (*update all references in render from `data` to `data`*).

```
const [data, setData] = useState(data1);
```

Similar approach as adding a new tab, get the new data name and title. Here we call `setData` and again use a functional state update, but this time we'll map the existing state to a new array. When the array index matches the active tab index this is the data object we need to updated. Spread its `myData` into a new array and append the new data object. If index isn't a match then just return the element.

```
const Create_element = () => {
  /**
   * window.prompt is just a quick way to request input from user. 
   */
  const data_name = window.prompt('Enter Data Name');
  const data_title = window.prompt('Enter Data Title');

  if (data_name && data_title) {
    setData(data => data.map((el, i) => i === active_menu ? {
      ...el,
      myData: [...el.myData, { data_name, data_title }],
    } : el))
  }
};
```

3. Suppose I have 3 tabs (data) so when page loads the first tab data I want to show, but it is not showing up I need to click there only it is showing up.

Issue here is caused by keeping a separate `nestedData` state object that is only ever updated when a tab is clicked. When a new element is added to the active tab's `myData` array `nestedData` isn't updated. Solution here is to simply render the nested data directly in the UI.

Update the tab's onClick handler to simply set the active menu (index).

```
onClick={() => setactive_menu(index)}
```

Render the `myData` directly from the new `data` state.

```
data[active_menu].myData.map((li, index) => (...
```

4. If the data is null then I can create up to 4 tabs this also I a=want some Idea to do it.

Conditionally rendering the ADD button will control this.

```
{data.length < 4 && <button onClick={addNewTab}>ADD</button>}
```

[image: Edit how-to-create-dynamic-elements-inside-global-tabs]

Full Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import RightBar from "./Right_option";
import NEsted from "./Nested";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814645/how-to-create-dynamic-elements-inside-global-tabs
 */

const data1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Maxi",
    myData: [
      {
        data_name: "div1",
        data_title: "div1 tittle"
      },
      {
        data_name: "div1",
        data_title: "div tittle"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Phill",
    myData: [
      {
        data_name: "div21",
        data_title: "div21 tittle"
      }
    ]
  }
];

/**
 * Data object constructor
 * @param {number} id new data object id
 * @param {string} name new data object name
 * @example
 * new Data(1, 'Bill')
 */
const Data = (id, name) => ({ id, name, myData: [] });

/**
 * Id generator hook
 * @param {number} [seed=0] initial id generator value
 * @returns {function}
 */
const useIdGenerator = (seed = 0) => {
  function* genId(seed = 0) {
    let i = seed;
    while (true) yield i++;
  }

  const generator = genId(seed);

  return () => generator.next().value;
};

export default function App() {
  const generateId = useIdGenerator(5);

  const [data, setData] = useState(data1);
  const [active_menu, setactive_menu] = useState(0);

  const Create_element = () => {
    /**
     * window.prompt is just a quick way to request input from user.
     */
    const data_name = window.prompt("Enter Data Name");
    const data_title = window.prompt("Enter Data Title");

    if (data_name && data_title) {
      setData((data) =>
        data.map((el, i) =>
          i === active_menu
            ? {
                ...el,
                myData: [...el.myData, { data_name, data_title }]
              }
            : el
        )
      );
    }
  };

  const addNewTab = () => {
    /**
     * window.prompt is just a quick way to request input from user.
     */
    const name = window.prompt("Enter Name");

    if (name) {
      setData((data) => [...data, new Data(generateId(), name)]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App row">
      {data.map((li, index) => (
        <div className="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" key={index}>
          <div
            className={
              index === active_menu
                ? "row dashboard_single_cont_active"
                : "row dashboard_single_cont"
            }
            onClick={() => setactive_menu(index)}
          >
            <div className="dashboard_name col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
              {li.name}
            </div>
            <div
              className={
                active_menu === index
                  ? "dashboard_option_active col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"
                  : "dashboard_option col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"
              }
              align="center"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      {data.length < 4 && <button onClick={addNewTab}>ADD</button>}

      <div className="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11">
        <div className="row">
          {data[active_menu].myData.map((li, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"
            >
              <NEsted data={li} />
              <br></br>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <RightBar Create_element={Create_element} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I checked your code, found out  that prompt is showing two times when ever i click on add or create element

Comment: @manishthakur Are you sure? I still have the sandbox open in a tab and can't reproduce any double window prompts (*the "create element" has two prompts, one for name and one for title*). Also, as the comment says, it's just a quick hack to get user input; you'll likely want to use a form and text input for better UX.

Comment: ya anyway I am not going to ask to user to input name, initially I only want to create a name like dash 1, dash 2, I can manipulate your code accordingly ? correct ?

Comment: @manishthakur Affirmative, any logic for getting new values is up to you. As mentioned, the prompts and id generator were just a quick way to get a value to update with.

Comment: I am getting error as `TypeError: Data is not a constructor`    at this line `setData((data) => [...data, new Data(id, name)]);`, this is the only thing where I have been stuck, do need to change any thing, I am getting data from server

Comment: @manishthakur Nope, just another quick hack to make instantiating a new object quick. You could just as easily do `setData((data) => [...data, { id, name, myData: [] }]);` if you've already a new `id` and `name` ready to go.

Comment: Hey I forget to mention one thing in each dashboard I ahve delete button, How can I delete the perticular dashboard If I want to

Comment: @manishthakur If by dashboard you mean the tab groups from the code snippets here, then array::filter is commonly used to filter the data by index, i.e. something like `const deleteTab = index => () => setData(data => data.filter((_, i) => i !== index));` where the button's onClick handler is `onClick={deleteTab(index)}`. If you delete a tab then you should also handle managing the active tab/menu/dashboard item as that can then make   `data[active_menu]` undefined when mapping the `myData` property.

Comment: Could you please update codesand box so that  I can get a clear picture

Comment: @manishthakur https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-create-dynamic-elements-inside-global-tabs-v2-with-delete-kzluz?file=/src/App.js Adds `deleteTab` handler, adds button, and uses Optional Chaining for null handling `data[active_menu]?.myData.map`.

Comment: hi sir, I was trying on new thing that is to delete the `myData` i.e which are inside dashboard so one of them I was trying to delete and I am doing like  this  `setData((data1) =>data1[0].myData.filter((_, i) => i !== index));`   I am getting error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`  and this error is coming where you have done optional chaining as you have mentioned above, I don't know what I am passing wrong.

Comment: @manishthakur You need to map data to a new array, and when the mapping index equals the active_menu, shallow copy that element into a new object *and then* you can do the `myData` filtering by index. I updated the last codesandbox I linked. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-create-dynamic-elements-inside-global-tabs-v2-with-delete-kzluz?file=/src/App.js